# LINQ to SQL - CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a DataContext (Linq to Sql) with about 47 tables.
I am trying to get a list of all 47 tables and print them to the CheckedListBox under TabControl "Tables"?
When the user checks any number of table name(s) associated to the CheckedListBox under "Tables" TabControl
-- I would like all column name(s) associated to CheckedListBox on the "Tables" TabControl to be print under the
"Columns" TabControl. Could Someone help? Thanks.

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(MyDataContext).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    if(property.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
    { 
        object[] attribs = property.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments()[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableA‌​ttribute), false); 
        if(attribs.Length > 0)
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(property.Name); 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So if this gets all the table names, is your question how can I add them to a CheckListBox?

Comment: I used ... tableCheckedListBox.Items.Add(tableCheckedListBox.Items.CheckedItems);       but it doesn't work quite like I expected. It print out "(Collection)" instead of the column names of the selected tables

Comment: Add that to the question. It will make it much clearer for people trying to answer it :)

Answer (score 0):

One solution that I can think of is using the Reflection to read the all the properties of the context class. and then again using the properties read properties of the selected checklist to get column names. here is a pointer for you to get you started

```
var tables = typeof(YourDataContextClassName).GetProperties(); // This will return you all public properties, use overloaded methods to get your desired properties

    // You have all tables now, get their name and then against each table, use the same technique to get their fields.
```

Comment: I used ... tableCheckedListBox.Items.Add(tableCheckedListBox.Items.CheckedItems); but it doesn't work quite like I expected. It print out "(Collection)" instead of the column names of the selected tables

Comment: please update your question with your latest code. That will give us help u

Comment: I am working with Windows form using LINQ to SQL. I am trying to figure out how to populate column names on "columnCheckedListBox" after selecting one or more table name(s) from the "tableCheckedListBox".

Currently, when selecting table name(s) on "tableCheckedListBox", the form populates "(Collection)" to "columnCheckedListBox". Instead of populating "(Collection)" to "columnCheckedListBox", I prefer to populate the column names to "columnCheckedListBox" from each selected table name on "tableCheckedListBox". Can you help? Thank you.